# Отключение масштабирования на мобилке(двумя пальцами)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, viewport

Цель: реализовать это как на https://m.vk.com
Пробовал прописать тот же meta viewport , результата не было. Проверяю на iphone 5s ,ipad-mini. Скриншоты для примера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

HTML мета тегом

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Или JS

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent || event;

    if(event.scale > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: А есть какое-то решение для ios устройств?